# CollectionViewSource filtering not displayed in view / combo box

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

i try to implement a filtering that is initialized after some processing and run into two problems. I extracted the code from our current project to focus on the problem. I am working with WPF/MVVM (.Net Framework 4.8).

The code posted below is only an abstraction and the data provided makes no sense, but it corresponds to the structure in our project, which makes more sense.

The idea is that after some data is selected (here represented by `PersonData`) additional data is loaded (here represented by `DeliveryData`) and assigned to the `DeliveryCollection`. A `CollectionViewSource` is initialized with the default view of the `DeliveryCollection`. To simulate this process i use a Button binded through a command (`InitListViewCommand`). The `DeliveryCollectionView` is binded to the itemsource of two combo box, each with an own converter to retrieve the correct data from the `DeliveryCollectionView / DeliveryCollection` (Town and Payment).

Here i got two problems:

**1.**

If i use the command (or click event in a non-MVVM app) the `DeliveryCollection` and the filter of the `CollectionViewSource` are correctly initialized. Nevertheless, the view is not updated. The combo box shows no values.

It works, if i put the `CollectionViewSource` initializer method into the constructor.

I can only think of that some binding is not correctly executed / set, if the initialize method is called outside of the constructor.

How do I get this to work outside of the constructor?

**2.**

If both combo box are set and i select a town, then the filter is correctly executed and removes the not matching delivery objects. But again, the view does not update so that the values within the combo box remain the same.
I thought that if i bind both combo box to the same `CollectionViewSource` i get the possibility to filter the `DeliverCollectionView` and the combo box.

What should i do, to update the view / combo box after the data is filtered?

You find my code below:

---

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="FilterTest2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FilterTest2"
        xmlns:converter="clr-namespace:FilterTest2.Converter"
        xmlns:localVM="clr-namespace:FilterTest2.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FilterTest 2" Height="100" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <localVM:MainViewModel></localVM:MainViewModel>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converter:TableBasisToTownListConverter x:Key="TableBasisToTownListConverter" />
            <converter:TableBasisToPaymentListConverter x:Key="TableBasisToPaymentListConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="28"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Init" Command="{Binding InitListViewCommand}">
        </Button>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbDeliveryTown" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DeliveryCollectionView, Converter={StaticResource TableBasisToTownListConverter}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTown}"></ComboBox>
        <ComboBox x:Name="cbDeliveryPayment" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DeliveryCollectionView, Converter={StaticResource TableBasisToPaymentListConverter}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPayment}"></ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
        }
    }
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<DeliveryData> _deliveryCollection;
        private ModelData _modelData;
        private string _selectedTown;
        private string _selectedPayment;

        public ICommand InitListViewCommand { get; private set; }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            InitListViewCommand = new RelayCommand(o => InitCollectionView());

            //InitCollectionView();
        }

        public string SelectedTown
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedTown;
            }
            set 
            {
                _selectedTown = value;
                DeliveryCollectionView.Refresh();
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTown");
            }
        }

        public string SelectedPayment
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedPayment;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedPayment = value;
                DeliveryCollectionView.Refresh();
                OnPropertyChanged("SelectedPayment");
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DeliveryData> DeliveryCollection
        {
            get { return _deliveryCollection; }
            set
            {
                _deliveryCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DeliveryCollection");
            }
        }

        ICollectionView _deliveryCollectionView;

        public ICollectionView DeliveryCollectionView
        {
            get
            {
                return _deliveryCollectionView;
            }
        }

        private bool DeliveryBasisFilter(DeliveryData delBasis)
        {
            bool ok = true;

            if (SelectedTown != null)
                if (ok == true && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedTown))
                    ok = delBasis.DeliveryTown.Equals(SelectedTown);
            if (SelectedPayment != null)
                if (ok == true && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedPayment))
                    ok = delBasis.DeliveryPayment.Equals(SelectedPayment);

            return ok;
        }

        public void InitCollectionView()
        {
            _modelData = new ModelData();

            _deliveryCollection = new ObservableCollection<DeliveryData>(_modelData.GetDelivery(1));

            _deliveryCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_deliveryCollection);
            _deliveryCollectionView.Filter = new Predicate<object>(o => DeliveryBasisFilter(o as DeliveryData));
        }
    }
```

**ModelData.cs**

```
public class ModelData
    {
        List<PersonData> _persons;
        Dictionary<int, List<DeliveryData>> _delivery;

        public ModelData()
        {
            _persons = new List<PersonData>();
            _persons.Add(new PersonData(1, "Michael", 30));
            _persons.Add(new PersonData(2, "Sarah", 18));
            _persons.Add(new PersonData(3, "John", 18));
            _persons.Add(new PersonData(4, "Hope", 25));
            _persons.Add(new PersonData(5, "Bart", 50));

            _delivery = new Dictionary<int, List<DeliveryData>>();
            _delivery.Add(1, new List<DeliveryData>() {
                new DeliveryData("Berlin", "PayPal", new List<string>() { "N1", "N2" }),
                new DeliveryData("NY", "All", new List<string>() { "N1" }),
                new DeliveryData("Berlin", "Visa", new List<string>() { "N1" })
            });
            _delivery.Add(2, new List<DeliveryData>() {
                new DeliveryData("Berlin", "All", new List<string>() { "N1" }),
                new DeliveryData("NY", "Visa", new List<string>() { "N1", "N2" })
            });
        }

        public List<PersonData> Persons 
        {
            get
            {
                return _persons;
            }
        }

        public List<DeliveryData> GetDelivery(int personId)
        {
            if (_delivery.ContainsKey(personId))
                return _delivery[personId];
            else
                return null;
        }
    }
```

**Converter.cs**

```
public class TableBasisToTownListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            List<string> townList = new List<string>();

            if (value == null)
                return townList;

            //IEnumerable<TableData> tabList = (IEnumerable<TableData>)value;
            IEnumerable<DeliveryData> tList = ((System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView)value).Cast<DeliveryData>();

            if (tList != null)
            {
                foreach (var tab in tList)
                {
                    townList.Add(tab.DeliveryTown);
                }

                townList = townList.Distinct().ToList();
            }

            townList.Insert(0, "");

            return townList;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class TableBasisToPaymentListConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            List<string> paymentList = new List<string>();

            if (value == null)
                return paymentList;

            //IEnumerable<TableData> tabList = (IEnumerable<TableData>)value;
            IEnumerable<DeliveryData> delList = ((System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView)value).Cast<DeliveryData>();

            if (delList != null)
            {
                foreach (var tab in delList)
                {
                    paymentList.Add(tab.DeliveryPayment);
                }
            }

            paymentList.Insert(0, "");

            return paymentList;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Regards

Comment: get rid of converter which creates a copy of data

Comment: @ASh I removed the converter from xaml, but nothing changed. If i call the initializer outside the constructor, the combo box are not updated.